# How can I prevent Javascript filter from causing my gridview header to not show?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

My goal was to create a web page with a gridview that can be filtered by any value but every time characters are entered into the filter the header disappears. I'm thinking that the filter is also filtering out the header but I couldn't be sure. Here is my code:

```html
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

      <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
         
            $("#fbody tbody").attr('id', 'testing');

        });

        var table = $('#fbody').DataTable();

        new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader(table, {
           
       

        });

       </script>



    <script>
         $(function () { // this will be called when the DOM is ready
             $('#MainContent_txtFilter').keyup(function () {
            //   alert ("hi");
                 //    var data = this.value.split(" ");
                 var data = this.value.toUpperCase().split(" ");
                 
                 var jo = $("#testing").find("tr");
                 if (this.value == "") {
                     jo.show();
                     
                     return;
                 }

                 //hide all the rows
                 jo.hide();
                 
                 //Recusively filter the jquery object to get results.
                 jo.filter(function (i, v) {
                     var $t = $(this);
                     for (var d = 0; d < data.length; ++d) {
                         //    if ($t.is(":contains('" + data[d] + "')")) {
                         if ($t.text().toUpperCase().indexOf(data[d]) > -1) {
                             return true;
                         }
                     }
                     return false;
                 })
                 //show the rows that match.
                 .show();
                
             }).focus(function () {
                 this.value = "";
                 $(this).css({
                     "color": "black"
                 });
                 $(this).unbind('focus');
             }).css
             ({
                 "color": "#C0C0C0"
             });

             });
        
    </script>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
  
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
    Filter: <asp:TextBox ID="txtFilter" runat="server" Width="110px"></asp:TextBox> 
        <br />
        <br />
      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
      
            <ContentTemplate>

            <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">  
      <br />
      
     

<div style="overflow:auto;height:400px;width:680px;" id="DivMainContent">
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Pricing" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database1 %>" SelectCommand="spPricing" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"></asp:SqlDataSource>

  
        
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                
                    AllowSorting="True" BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="2" ForeColor="Black" DataSourceID="Pricing" DataKeyNames="ItemCode">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemCode"                                              HeaderText="ItemCode" SortExpression="ItemCode"                                   ReadOnly="True" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemCodeDesc"                                          HeaderText="ItemCodeDesc" SortExpression="ItemCodeDesc">
                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price"                              SortExpression="Price" >
                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                        </asp:BoundField>

                </asp:GridView>
        
        
         
</div>

</asp:Panel>
  </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>





</asp:Content>
```

My Code behind:

```html
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    
    GridView2.Attributes.Add("id", "fbody");
    
 
}
```

Please let me know if there's anything that can be done to keep the header after gridview has been filtered. I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>To ensure you're only targetting rows in the body of the table, limit the jQuery selector to the `tbody` region of the table, e.g.:</strike>

```
var jo = $("#testing").find("tbody tr");
```

This should cause the `thead` region to be ignored and thus unaffected.

Sorry, after re-reading your code I finally noticed that the `#testing` ID is already pointing at the `tbody`.  What doesn't help is that the GridView control has a nasty habit of including everything within the `tbody`, including the header.

As a potential workaround, try wiring up an `OnRowDataBound` handler:

```
protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header) {
        e.Row.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
    }
}
```

This should cause the header to be rendered within a semantically-correct `thead` element, leaving you able to target `tbody` without affecting the headers.

Comment: I appreciate the response. I tried this one and it didn't work. The gridview didn't filter anything. Isn't this section of the code just saying what part of the gridview should be returned? I was thinking that the .find("tr") was just saying "if you find a cell that matches the filter, then return that whole row".For example, if you replaced the "tr" with a "td" and  if "green" were entered into the textbox then the filter returns all cells containing "green". Let me know if that seems right.

Comment: It's been a while but I used similar code today for another project and your suggestion works very well. I must have missed something else last time i tried using it. Sorry for the delay and thanks very much for the help.

Comment: No problem, glad it came in useful :)